# Controll Acrobat reader installation from custom Installer

Tags: windows-installer, acrobat

Hi the action that I want to do is Following:

I want to install a progrram that require AcrobatReader MinVersion 9.0.
With custom installer I check if exist in destination computer, if not I install it with Process class.

Process.Start(@"c:\File.exe").WaitForExit();

The problem is that in this way I haven't check of installation state.

How can I retrieve this status ?

In practice I want to know if installation done well or not to confirm or unistall my program

Thanking in advance

Piercarlo

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two windows-installer installations running at the same time, so this method will always fail if you're using Windows Installer methods (Adobe uses Windows Installer)

Comment: Yes this I know and to resolve I used one backgroundworker to run AcrobatReader setup.exe, the question is how can I retrieve information about installation state of acrobat

Comment: Assuming you have a distribution agreement for Adobe Reader (as per their EULA) then just use the MSI instead of the EXE and use the Windows Installer API to verify the state.